# How to resolve potential permission issue in oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, oracle11g

I've got a synonym pointing to a table:

```
-- Create the synonym 
create or replace synonym MY_SCHEMA.COLORS_ALL
                      for OTHER_SCHEMA.MV_CAR_COLORS;
```

Problem is that I can query this synonym fine:

```
select * 
  from MY_SCHEMA.COLORS_ALL;
```

however, when I try to use this synonym in a `stored procedure` I get an error that `table or view does not exist.`

What could causing this issue? Recently the target table (MV) `MV_CAR_COLORS` was refreshed and indices on it were refreshed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need direct grants (not through a role) on the table to the owner of the stored procedure.  If by "refreshed" you mean the table was dropped and recreated, you probably didn't re-grant this direct grant as part of the refresh process.

Comment: `select * from dba_tab_privs where grantee in ('PUBLIC', 'my_schema') and grantor = 'OTHER_SCHEMA' and table_name = 'COLORS_ALL'` fetches a row so I am assuming that direct grants are there

Comment: Interesting - what are the contents of that row?

Comment: The privs on the synonym don't give you privs on the MV_CAR_COLORS object. I think you'll need SELECT and REFERENCES privileges on that table

Comment: @Gary - sorry, no such thing as privileges on a synonym in Oracle.  You're right about the SELECT privilege (not REFERENCES), and we'll have to see what is coming back from dba_tab_privs to make a determination.  After reading the original question again, I'm wondering about the my_schema qualification in the SELECT was intentional.

Comment: Whoops. dpbradley is right. You can grant on a synonym, but it appears in the underlying ***_tab_privs as a grant to the object. I got confused with views which can have their own grants.